# python - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django, windows-7

Следую инструкции на http://djangobook.com/installing-django/. Возникает ошибка при запуске сервера.

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>   January 10, 2017 - 16:13:57
>   Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> Unhandled exception in thread started by function check_errors.locals.wrapper
>    at 0x0357BE88
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\saneklol\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.p
>   y", line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\saneklol\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\co
>   mmands\runserver.py", line 144, in inner_run
>       ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
>     File "C:\Users\saneklol\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\baseh
>   ttp.py", line 183, in run
>       httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
>     File "C:\Users\saneklol\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\baseh
>   ttp.py", line 76, in **init**
>       super(WSGIServer, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in **init**
>       self.server_bind()
>     File "C:\Users\saneklol\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\baseh
>   ttp.py", line 80, in server_bind
>       super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
>     File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
>       HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
>     File "c:\python\Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
>       self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
>     File "c:\python\Lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
>       hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 9: invalid
>   continuation byte

Что делать?

Comment: Версия Python какая?

Comment: Версия - Python 3.6.0

Comment: python.exe manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 так работает? Рекомендуют сменить имя компьютера на латинские буквы.

Comment: Да, так работает.

Comment: вы можете сменить имя компьютера?

Comment: Да, уже сделал. Теперь python manage.py runserver выполняется корректно. Большое спасибо.