# Как исправить данную ошибку в Django?

Tags: python, django

Недавно начал изучать Django, выскакивает ошибка при запуске локального сервера:  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 8: invalid continuation byte` . Имя пользователя на английском. Пытался вводить `python manage.py runserver 8000` а так же `python manage.py 127.0.0.1:8000`. Я подавлен, поэтому не могу сейчас нормально мыслить. Подскажите, в чём моя проблема? Слышал, что тут вина питона:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 20, 2020 - 11:42:21
Django version 3.1, using settings 'newsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Games\siteone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Games\siteone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    run(self.addr, int(self.port), handler,
  File "D:\Games\siteone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "D:\Games\siteone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\megared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Имя компьютера точно не содержит в себе кириллицу?

Comment: Имя пользователя - megared, англ. символами.

Comment: Очень похоже на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612849/201445 Кст, а что возвращает `import socket; print(socket.getfqdn())` ?

Comment: @megared имя компьютера, а не пользователя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что имя вашего компьютера содержит кириллические символы.

> Hostnames are composed of series of labels concatenated with dots, as
> are all domain names. For example, "en.wikipedia.org" is a hostname.
> Each label must be between 1 and 63 characters long, and the entire
> hostname (including the delimiting dots but not a trailing dot) has a
> maximum of 253 ASCII characters.
>
> The Internet standards for protocols mandate that component **hostname
> labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a
> case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen
> ('-')**. The original specification of hostnames in RFC 952, mandated
> that labels could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must
> not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent specification (RFC 1123)
> permitted hostname labels to start with digits. **No other symbols,
> punctuation characters, or white space are permitted**.